DB2 return table in function
I am using DB2 LUW, but got error when try to create the function...
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_TT ()
 RETURNS TABLE (ID CHAR(1))
 LANGUAGE SQL
 READS SQL DATA
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN ATOMIC
   RETURN
     SELECT '1'
     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
 END


How did you create the function? You have to change the character for "end of statement" (terminator). It seems the ";" is the issue.

Whatever tool you are using to submit the create or replace function has to be configured properly, to use an alternate statement delimiter (and you have to put that delimiter after the final END in your block) , so that the database can distinguish between the end of a statement AND the end of a block.  This is a FAQ.

I just execute the sql inside my db2 client.  When I omit the character ';', I got same error.

What is your Db2 client?  The exact tool.  You have to configure that tool.  Are you using a GUI app?  Are you using the command-line / terminal ? What is your operating system?

Windows, DB Visualizer

This is a frequently asked question.
Currently shipping versions of DBVisualizer allow by default SQL Block Identifiers (characters you use to specify the start and the end of a block) ,  and DbViZ also allows the @delimiter command to let you choose a character (or two characters) to temporarily-indicate the end of a block.
Read the Dbvis docs carefully.
See the documentation here https://www.dbvis.com/docs/ug/working-with-sql/executing-complex-statements/
But take care. If you plan to deploy scripts using a different automated tool (different from Dbvisualizer) then you need a different method. This will depend on the tool you use for such deployments. Most people use the command-line and scripting, in which case the Db2 CLP (command line processor) is very script friendly. It supports specifying the delimiter within the SQL script via the --#SET TERMINATOR method, and also allows to specify the block terminator on the command-line via options (-td...) . For example to use the @ symbol to indicate the end of a block when using the Db2 command-line-processor to submit the SQL, you can use either --#SET TERMINATOR @ inside the script (you can use it as many times as you like inside a script, including to revert back to the default ; when you want to use non-block simple statements again),  or as alternate you can specify -td@ on the command-line in which case that delimiter will apply to every statement inside the script being executed as a script via db2 -tf your_script.sql -td@
